# I want to monitor, whether the click happened inside or outside of the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to monitor, whether the click happened inside or outside of the component.

But i am getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined"

```
export default class M1Component extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false);
  }

  handleClick = e => {
    if(this.node.contains(e.target)){
      console.log("component inside click");
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("component outside click");
    }
  }

  render() { 
    return(
        <div className="form-group" ref={node => this.node = node}>
            ...
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When ever I am trying to print those values,

```
console.log(e.target); // getting the div value
console.log(this.refs.node); // getting undefined
```

Comment: `console.log(this.refs.node); // getting undefined` is expected since your are using callback refs, and would access it like `this.node`

Comment: Is `this` returning `undefined` in your app?

Comment: Hi Shubham, it is giving undefined for both "this.refs.node" or "this.node"

Comment: Yeah Bhojendra, its giving error for me.

Comment: Sorry then, you must provide a fiddle that has bug. Without it we cannot debug.

Comment: Any other way,i an get the value of click event?what ever i am trying through refs